# AMP page invalid meta name="amp-ad-refresh"

Tags: amp-html

I'd like to add the feature AMP Ad Refresh according to this article:

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-ad-network-doubleclick-impl/amp-ad-network-doubleclick-impl-internal.md#sra-single-request-architecture-alpha

Unfortunately in [my AMP page](http://m.voetbalzone.nl/amp/doc.asp?uid=323073#development=1), I get an error in my console as well as in my extension:

> The attribute 'name' in tag 'meta name= and content=' is set to the
>   invalid value 'amp-ad-refresh'.

But according to the article, it is a valid tag.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors#invalid-attribute-value). The `Invalid attribute value` error indicates that an HTML tag has an attribute with an allowed name, but not an allowed value. For example, one common trigger for this error is invalid values for URLs. All URLs values (in href and src attributes) must match one of these [possible attribute values](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp).